# Preparing for Yeoman 1.0 -> this.installDependencies not working anymore

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, jhipster

I am working on migrating [JHipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster) to Yeoman 0.20.1, in order to prepare for Yeoman 1.0.

At the end of our process, we normally:

- Run `npm install` and `bower install`
- Use a callback function to run some Grunt or Gulp.js task, usually `grunt wiredep`

This has always worked, and [here is the current code](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/c4d9e2c2336f957104d3b08b5d9e0c29e28207cb/app/index.js#L19) that runs the installation process.

Since I migrated to Yeoman 0.20.1, we still have:

- The `installDependencies` function being called
- It even prints out the message `I'm all done. Running npm install & bower install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.`

But in fact no installation happens! NPM and Bower do not install anything, and our Grunt task is not called. Note that if I call them manually, they work correctly.

If tried to debug this, and it looks like [this method](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/5442088385bbbf41a183a65d21f1493f4b060096/lib/actions/install.js#L43) is not being called.

Can anybody help me on this issue?

Comment: `skipInstall: options['skip-install'],` have you checked this value?

Comment: yes, when I debug it I get `skipInstall: false`

Comment: Their tests are doing the same thing: [this is strange](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/test/install.js). Have you tried `npmInstall()` and `bowerInstall()` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried those methods: I enter those methods, but the `this.env.runLoop.add('install', function (done) {` is still not called at the end. I don't think this makes a difference to call them manually or througt the installDependencies method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the run loop might be done after the `end` event is triggered. `installDependencies` schedule install methods to be runned during the `install` priority. If the run loop is done, they won't run.

You should be able to just call `installDependencies` at any time and not worry about the `end` event callback. If you want to imitate the behavior you currently have, then call `installDependencies` inside a method called `end`.

---

As a side note on the installDependencies API, you don't need to manually specify `skipInstall` anymore (that's now automatic).

Comment: Thanks Simon, it's working! I'll do further tests, I'll post any updates here if there is anything new.